# How to ignore text when centering equations in the align* environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I'm writing out some lines in the `align*` environment and I want to add a comment to one line, and then it shifts the entire section over to the left. Ideally I'd want `align` to center the equations and ignore the text in the alignment.

For now I'm not overly concerned with what happens if I end up needing to wrap the text over multiple lines, but I'd be interested in how to deal with that as well.

Sample code:

```
\begin{align*}
    a &= b+c\\
    b &= a-c
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    a &= b+c \text{this comment should not affect the position.}\\
    b &= a-c
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Are you perhaps looking for something like `\tag{some text}`?

Comment: @gz839918 That looks good, but the spacing seems to affect the alignment anyway.  Is there a way to reduce this spacing?

Comment: The spacing exists to prevent text from overflowing onto the equation and affecting the appearance of the document. There's probably some way to disable it, but I don't know personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effectively requests the comment to be set in a zero-width box. This will, however, cause (lengthy) content to spill over into the margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a &= b + c \\
  b &= a - c
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  a &= b + c \makebox[0pt][l]{~this comment should not affect the position.} \\
  b &= a - c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

In those instances, you can use a `tabular` to structure the content vertically:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a &= b + c \\
  b &= a - c
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  a &= b + c \makebox[0pt][l]{~%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      this comment should not \\ 
      affect the position.\end{tabular}} \\
  b &= a - c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems to give everything I was hoping for!  Thank you!